# How to use specific network connection with NSURLSession (OS X)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlsession, appkit

Cannot find `NSURLSessionConfiguration` property to select certain network connection (wired, wi-fi etc.) `NSURLSession` to work with.

Already got current interfaces list (with `ifaddrs` struct), now I need to figure out, how to use this data by `NSURLSession` instance.

Comment: You're way too high-level a the `NSURLSession` API for sending requests/responses via a specific network interface. If you want to accomplish it, then you'll have to go way further down the stack.

Comment: @Petesh seems like `NSURLSession` was built only for using for cocoa-touch projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you are going to face here is that the OS will only be using one network adapter at one time.  So NSURLSession will just use whichever one is active.  You would have to somehow manually switch the user's network adapter settings to use Wifi/wired

Comment: I disagree with this answer - macOS is perfectly capable of maintaining multiple network adapters. The routing tables will always prefer one of them for a given destination address, but at the TCP socket layer it *is* possible to influence that decision, see the --interface argument to curl(1)